# Oracle data dictionary

Tags: oracle, oracle19c, data-dictionary

Considering the following information from the Oracle data dictionary
When the following command is executed, to obtain the information

```
SELECT grantee,owner,table_name,grantor, privilege, grantable
FROM user_tabs_privs;
```

[image]

What is the SQL statements that have been issued to cause these grants to exist in the
dictionary? Also for each statement which user has executed the statement?

Comment: Is this a job interview question? What's the background?

Comment: it is a part of a question paper .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after you run the following steps, you can get the result you want

(1) firstly login as Ann,run the SQL statement:
grant select on project to Billy with grant option;
(2) still as Ann, runt the SQL statement:
grant delete on employee to marlam ;
(3) login as Billy, run the SQL statement:
grant select on project to leah ;

Answer (score 2):

Review this example and compare it to your output; you'll see which command leads to which result.

User `mike`:

```
SQL> show user
USER is "MIKE"
SQL> SELECT grantee,owner,table_name,grantor, privilege, grantable
  2  FROM user_tab_privs;

no rows selected
```

User `scott` will grant a few things to `mike`:

```
SQL> connect scott/tiger
Connected.
SQL> grant select on test to mike;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> grant delete on dept to mike with grant option;

Grant succeeded.
```

Back to `mike`, see what has happened:

```
SQL> connect mike/lion
Connected.
SQL> SELECT grantee,owner,table_name,grantor, privilege, grantable
  2  FROM user_tab_privs;

GRANTEE OWNER  TABLE_NAME GRANTOR    PRIVILEGE  GRANTABLE
------- ------ ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
MIKE    SCOTT  DEPT       SCOTT      DELETE     YES
MIKE    SCOTT  TEST       SCOTT      SELECT     NO

SQL>
```